# call popToRootViewController from another tab

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, poptoviewcontroller

I have tab bar with navigation controller app using storyboard ,
my purpose is to press a button in tab3 and in the background I want tab1 to "popToRootViewController"

the button in tab3 viewcontroller:

```
- (IBAction)Action:(id)sender {

    vc1 * first = [[vc1 alloc]init];
    [first performSelector:@selector(popToRootViewController) withObject:Nil];

}
```

the code in the tab1 viewcontroller

```
-(void)popToRootViewController{

    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    NSLog(@"popToRootViewController");
}
```

I get the `popToRootViewController` in logs, but the action didn't perform.

***that solve the problem:***

```
- (IBAction)Action:(id)sender {

        [[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are doing it:

```
vc1 * first = [[vc1 alloc]init];
[first performSelector:@selector(popToRootViewController) withObject:Nil];
```

is not correct. Indeed, you are creating a whole new controller here, completely independent from your existing controllers and not belonging to any navigation controller. For this reason, `self.navigationController` is `nil` in `popToRootViewController`.

You might try doing something like:

```
 //-- this will give you the left-most controller in your tab bar controller
 vc1 * first = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
[first performSelector:@selector(popToRootViewController) withObject:Nil];
```

Comment: @user2920421: could you check which value you get for `first`? also would you use this log: `NSLog(@"popToRootViewController: %@", self.navigationController);`...

Answer (score 1):

Bind TabBar with tabBarViewController-
In tabBarViewController.m

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSArray *array = [tabBarController viewControllers];
    if([[array objectAtIndex:tabBarController.selectedIndex] isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
        [(UINavigationController *)[array objectAtIndex:tabBarController.selectedIndex] popToRootViewControllerAnimated: NO];
}
```

It worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
To press a button in tab3 and in the background I want tab1 to "popToRootViewController"
```

If you want to perform `popToRootViewController` in tab1 by pressing button in tab3 then i would like to suggest use `NSNotificationCenter`. For example follow below code:-

In your `firstViewController` class add the observer of `NSNotification`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(yourMethod:)
                                                name:@"popToRootViewControllerNotification" object:nil];
}

-(void)yourMethod:(NSNotification*)not
{
 [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

In your `ThirdViewController`  class post the `notification` in below code:-

```
- (IBAction)Action:(id)sender {

 //   vc1 * first = [[vc1 alloc]init];
  //  [first performSelector:@selector(popToRootViewController) withObject:Nil];

//Post your notification here
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"popToRootViewControllerNotification" object:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your tab1 and tab2 arein different navigationController, then try this in `- (IBAction)action:(id)sender`

```
NSArray *viewControllers = [self.tabbarController viewControllers];
for (UIViewController *viewController in viewControllers) {
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[vc1 class]]) {
        vc1 * first = (vc1 *) viewController;
        [first.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
}
```